# Merge between siblings branch of svn

Tags: svn

My project has big volatile code base and different team are working on same code, so total number of files getting affected daily is huge in number. I recently faced a problem as two of the team has to merge their codes. I will explain the scenario.

My team has branched out from trunk and daily do a down merge from trunk to keep the code base in sync with trunk. There will at least 500 files getting affected daily. Once we finish our code we used to reintegrate to trunk and then do a records only merge back to branch so we can use continue working in branch. Now recently due to early release we are not able to upmerge to trunk, so for getting different team changes we branched out another branch from trunk and then decided to merge all our changes to the new branch, but as we do not have any merge history between my branch and new branch, what I could see, when I try full merge to new branch from my team branch, svn is trying to apply the changes we received from trunk as part of down merge to new branch. The new branch has all the changes as we branched from trunk recently and it is resulting in lots of tree conflicts. I am also not able to reintegrate because it is not trunk.

Could you please suggest any work around on this or any way out of this problem?